# Issue while configuring dynamic url for reverse proxy in httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, proxypass

I am trying to configure a dynamic url for reverse proxy in the httpd.conf of the Apache server. Below is the format in which I am trying to configure the url in the httpd.conf file,
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar/xyz?hello.
But on testing this configuration, I see that url gets malformed ( the **"?"** gets resolved into **"%3f"**). It would be great if someone could help me on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot add a query part here. Such is not part of an actual URL, but part of the requests payload.

Comment: RewriteRule helped me to combine the query param with the ProxyPaas url.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by combining 'RewriteRule' and 'ProxyPaas' ,

ProxyPaas /foo http:/foo.example.com/bar/xyz
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  /xyz  /xyz?hello[NE,R]